# Python: select digits from NoneType object

Tags: python, string

I have a 'NoneType' object like:

```
A='ABC:123'
```

I would like to get an object keeping only the digits:

```
A2=digitsof(A)='123'
```

Comment: That's not a NoneType, that's a string. What did you try so far?

Comment: No, you do **not** have a `NoneType` object; you have a string.

Comment: What should happen if there are non-consecutive digits? `'ABC:123:456'`?

Answer (score 4):

Split at the colon:

```
>>> A='ABC:123'
>>> numA = int(A.split(':')[1])
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions?

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> A = 'ABC:123' 
>>> sub(r'\D', '', A)
123
```

Comment: **Note:** All the comments on the question itself are quite right. That is a `string`, not a `NoneType`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> import re
>>> def digitsof(a):
...     return [int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', a) ]
...
>>> digitsof('ABC:123')
[123]
>>> digitsof('ABC:123,123')
[123, 123]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter function

```
A='ABC:123'    
filter(lambda s: s.isdigit(), A)
```

Comment: you are getting ABC, change it to isdigit()